# Rendering Depth Map in Unreal Engine

Tags: shader, depth, unreal-engine4

I try to build a shader in Unreal which is able to render the depth to an image like this post in Unity

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/877170/render-scene-depth-to-a-texture.html

Comment: Good for you... What is the question?

Comment: :D The question is "how?". I found this [post](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Content/Tools/RenderToTextureTools/4/) but this solution is stupid. Could somebody help to find a shader doing the same in unreal?